# change counter color in js

Tags: javascript, data-binding, event-handling, dom-events, counter

i want to change color to green when my counter number were grater than zero and change to red when counter less than zero

```js
const addBtn = document.getElementById(`add`);
const resetBtn = document.getElementById(`reset`);
const minusBtn = document.getElementById(`minus`);

const counter = document.getElementById(`counter`);

if (counter.innerHTML > 0) {
    counter.classList.remove(`white`)
    counter.classList.add(`green`)
}

addBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    counter.innerHTML = Number(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
});

minusBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
        counter.innerHTML -= 1;
});

resetBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    counter.innerHTML = 0;
});
```

what should i do?

Comment: Put `getElementById` strings in quotes like `getElementById("add")`.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen why so? I mean, I too don't use backquote, unless I intend to use `{...}` expressions in it (exactly like, in python, I don't use f-string if they don't contain any `{...}` expressions). But still, it is one of the 3 valid string encloser. And it is clearly not the problem here. Maybe it cost some nanoseconds at parse time because of the search for `${...}` pattern in it, but there is no other inconvenient, I am aware of. If you know what, I would be interested to know.

Comment: @chrslg I'm not really sure what you mean *exactly* but `const counter = document.getElementById(counter);` results in error `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'counter' before initialization` which probably means that the element can't be accessed.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen Yes, surely. But there is no such line of code in the message. For what I meant, I was under the impression that you were after the backquotes : ` (that I can't use to quote the line of code that I see, since they are also the code markdown of comments)

Comment: @chrslg The confusion likely arose from the initial revision of the question, where the code was not formatted properly.

Comment: @Unmitigated Oh, indeed. The comment was from 30 seconds before the formatting. That explains it (the answer to my comment date from 6 hours later tho :D, which didn't help understanding the misunderstanding)

Comment: @Errorist ... Regarding all the so far provided answers, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 2):

Create a function and update as per your requirement

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<button id="minus">Minus</button>
<div id="counter"></div>

<script>
  const addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
  const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
  const minusBtn = document.getElementById('minus');
  const counter = document.getElementById('counter');

  function updateCounterColor() {
    const counterValue = Number(counter.innerHTML);
    
    if (counterValue > 0) {
      counter.style.color = 'green';
    } else if (counterValue < 0) {
      counter.style.color = 'red';
    } else {
      counter.style.color = 'black';
    }
  }

  addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.innerHTML = Number(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
    updateCounterColor();
  });

  minusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.innerHTML = Number(counter.innerHTML) - 1;
    updateCounterColor();
  });

  resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    counter.innerHTML = 0;
    updateCounterColor();
  });

  updateCounterColor();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that checks for the value and changes the color whenever you click on `addBtn`, `minusBtn`, and `resetBtn`.

```js
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
const resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
const minusBtn = document.getElementById("minus");
const counter = document.getElementById("counter");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    counter.innerHTML = Number(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
    checkValue();
});

minusBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    counter.innerHTML -= 1;
    checkValue();
});

resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    counter.innerHTML = 0;
    checkValue();
});

function checkValue() {
    if (counter.innerHTML > 0) {
        counter.style.color = "green";
    } else if (counter.innerHTML < 0) {
        counter.style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<button id="minus">Minus</button>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

changed a little bit but should get you closer to what you are looking for:

```
const addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
const minusBtn = document.getElementById('minus');

const counter = document.getElementById('counter');

if (counter.innerHTML > 0) {
  counter.classList.remove('white');
  counter.classList.add('green');
} else if (counter.innerHTML < 0) {
  counter.classList.remove('white');
  counter.classList.add('red');
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter.innerHTML = Number(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
  if (counter.innerHTML > 0) {
    counter.classList.remove('white');
    counter.classList.add('green');
  } else if (counter.innerHTML < 0) {
    counter.classList.remove('white');
    counter.classList.add('red');
  }
});

minusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter.innerHTML = Number(counter.innerHTML) - 1;
  if (counter.innerHTML > 0) {
    counter.classList.remove('white');
    counter.classList.add('green');
  } else if (counter.innerHTML < 0) {
    counter.classList.remove('white');
    counter.classList.add('red');
  } 
});

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 counter.innerHTML = 0;
  counter.classList.remove('green', 'red');
  counter.classList.add('white');
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can define a separate function to change the count, and call it in each event handler. This function can then handle setting the color.

```js
function changeCount(val, upd=false) {
    const newCount = upd ? val : +counter.textContent + val;
    counter.textContent = newCount;
    counter.classList.toggle('green', newCount > 0);
    counter.classList.toggle('red', newCount < 0);
}
addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    changeCount(1);
});
minusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    changeCount(-1);
});
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    changeCount(0, true);
});
```

Comment: See the code working here: https://jsfiddle.net/bjscn6ug/

Comment: Don't post links to external JSFiddles. Use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead when possible.

Comment: @MichaelM. The relevant code is already in the answer. The JSFiddle is only an additional resource since it is unnecessary to include all the setup code.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you click a button you have to check if the value is >/< 0 so you need to use that `If statement` in all your `eventListeners` and it's better to create a function that can do that so that you keep your code clean.

```
      const addBtn = document.getElementById("add");
      const resetBtn = document.getElementById("reset");
      const minusBtn = document.getElementById("minus");
      const counter = document.getElementById("counter");

      const checkCounterValue=()=>{
            if (counter.innerHTML > 0) {
                counter.classList.remove("white", "red")
                counter.classList.add("green")
            }else if(counter.innerHTML < 0 ){
                counter.classList.remove("green", "white")
                counter.classList.add("red")
            }
      }

      addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
          counter.innerHTML = Number(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
          checkCounterValue()
      });

      minusBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
              counter.innerHTML -= 1;
              checkCounterValue()
      });

      resetBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
          counter.innerHTML = 0;
          counter.classList.remove("green", "red")
          counter.classList.add("white")
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

**One approach was to let the e.g. `<output/>` element's appearance get handled by [*attribute selectors*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) which are targeting the element's `data-output-value`** ... e.g. ...

- An attribute selector like ...

  ```css
  [data-output-value] {
    color: green;
  }
  ```

  ... would  define the default text color of an element which features such [an attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attr).
- Whereas an attribute selector like ...

  ```css
  [data-output-value^="-"] {
    color: red;
  }
  ```

  ... does target each element where its [attribute value does start](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_4) with a `dash`/`-`. Such an element's text color would be set to `red` for e.g. every negative value.
- A neutral `black` text color would be defined for an [attribute value equal to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue) Zero/`0` ...

  ```css
  [data-output-value="0"] {
    color: black;
  }
  ```

The OP's JS code then would remain almost unchanged for it does not need to actively deal with the counter-value based color-change.

Instead, in addition to updating the visible counter value, one also does update the counter element's newly introduced `data-output-value` attribute via this element's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property.

```js
const addBtn = document.getElementById('add');
const resetBtn = document.getElementById('reset');
const minusBtn = document.getElementById('minus');

const counter = document.getElementById('counter');

addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter.value = Number(counter.value) + 1;   // - counter value update.
  counter.dataset.outputValue = counter.value; // - attribute value update.
 
});
minusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter.value -= 1;                          // - counter value update.
  counter.dataset.outputValue = counter.value; // - attribute value update.
});
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  counter.value = 0;                           // - counter value update.
  counter.dataset.outputValue = counter.value; // - attribute value update.
});
```

```css
[data-output-value] {
  color: green;  
}
[data-output-value^="-"] {
  color: red;  
}
[data-output-value="0"] {
  color: black;  
}
output { margin-left: 1em; font-weight: 700; }
```

```html
<button id="add">increment</button>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
<button id="minus">decrement</button>

<output id="counter" data-output-value="0">0</output>
```

One of cause could implement the above example code more generic where one would read the incrementation values from each button (the one for incrementing and the one for decrementing). This approach needs just two handler functions, one for handling the value update of an output element and the other one for resetting the output value. Both handlers would write the current value once to the output element's `value` property and, as already shown, additionally to the element's `data-output-value` attribute.

And in order to be more flexible with the to be operated element nodes, one could implement both handler functions with a `this` context which refers the output-element, whereas the current event target does point to the decrementing / incrementing element-node where one would read the incrementing value from. The two concrete handler functions are getting created at the time of [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)ing the output element to each of the implemented handler functions.

```js
function handleValueUpadateAtBoundOutput({ currentTarget }) {
  const elmOutput = this;

  const incrementBy = parseFloat(currentTarget.dataset.increment);
  const result = parseFloat(elmOutput.dataset.outputValue) + incrementBy;
  
  elmOutput.dataset.outputValue = result;
  elmOutput.value = result;
}
function handleValueResetAtBoundOutput() {
  const elmOutput = this;
 
  elmOutput.dataset.outputValue = 0;
  elmOutput.value = 0;
}
const elmOutput = document.querySelector('[data-output-value]');

const handleValueUpadate =
  handleValueUpadateAtBoundOutput.bind(elmOutput);

const handleValueReset =
  handleValueResetAtBoundOutput.bind(elmOutput);

document
  .querySelector('[data-reset]')
  .addEventListener('click', handleValueReset);
 
document
  .querySelector('[data-add]')
  .addEventListener('click', handleValueUpadate);
document
  .querySelector('[data-subtract]')
  .addEventListener('click', handleValueUpadate);
```

```css
[data-output-value] {
  color: green;  
}
[data-output-value^="-"] {
  color: red;  
}
[data-output-value="0"] {
  color: black;  
}
output { margin-left: 1em; font-weight: 700; }
```

```html
<button data-add data-increment="2">increment</button>
<button data-reset>reset</button>
<button data-subtract data-increment="-2">decrement</button>

<output data-output-value="0">0</output>
```